# MySQL: Update field not working

Tags: mysql

This should be simple but I am missing something. The following is supposed to look in the game table and set winner_id to 9999 where the `winner_id` is NULL.

The query executes none of the records gets updated with 9999. The winner_id column is set to varchar 10.

```
UPDATE game 
SET winner_id = 9999 
WHERE winner_id = NULL LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`= NULL` will not work, use: `IS NULL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `IS` when comparing to `NULL` instead of `=`

```
UPDATE game 
SET winner_id = 9999 
WHERE winner_id IS NULL 
LIMIT 1
```

Because comparing to `null` results in `unknown` with `=`.